# Program to count balance of credit

Tags: python

Write a program to calculate the credit card balance after one year if a person only pays the minimum monthly payment required by the credit card company each month.

I am trying to write a program which would print the final balance left to pay after one year

```
balance = 4213

annualInterestRate = 0.2

monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04

month = 1

new_balance = (balance - (balance*monthlyPaymentRate))*(1+(annualInterestRate/12))


while month < 13:
    print "Month: " + str(month)
    print "Minimum monthly payment: " + str(round(minimum_monthly_payment, 2))
    print "Remaining balance: " + str(round(new_balance, 2))
    month += 1
```

My output shows this:

```
Month: 1
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 4111.89

Month: 2
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 4111.89

Month: 3
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 4111.89
```

But I should get something like this:

```
Month: 1
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 4111.89

Month: 2
Minimum monthly payment: 164.48
Remaining balance: 4013.2

Month: 3
Minimum monthly payment: 160.53
Remaining balance: 3916.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the variable `new_balance`, you should only modify the variable `balance`:

```
while month < 13:
    print "Month: " + str(month)
    print "Minimum monthly payment: " + str(round(minimum_monthly_payment, 2))
    balance = (balance - (balance*monthlyPaymentRate))*(1+(annualInterestRate/12))
    print "Remaining balance: " + str(round(balance, 2))
    month += 1
```

**output:**

```
Month: 1
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 4111.89
Month: 2
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 4013.2
Month: 3
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3916.89
Month: 4
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3822.88
Month: 5
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3731.13
Month: 6
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3641.58
Month: 7
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3554.19
Month: 8
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3468.89
Month: 9
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3385.63
Month: 10
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3304.38
Month: 11
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3225.07
Month: 12
Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
Remaining balance: 3147.67
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I just watched a video on while loop and just saw my mistake. I did not put balance as a variable into the loop and it was not modified after the loop...Thank you. :)

Comment: @user1692479 Glad it helped. :) If the answered helped you then you can accept it by checking the tick on the left hand side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing 3 times the same line: `new_balance = (balance - (balance*monthlyPaymentRate))*(1+(annualInterestRate/12))`

You don't have anything variabel in here which will update after each while loop.
You should update `balance` to get each time a lower number.

Comment: The repeated output is from the while loop - and definitely not printed out by that line, which only occurs once.

Comment: well yes, but you have to to update the "balance" in order to keep getting lower values. Else you're doing math like this:
A=1, B=1,
A+B=C,
A+B=C,
A+B=C,
A+1; <-- this one is missing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your values aren't updating, as you're forgetting to update the balance every month! Try updating your `balance` variable once every loop, like this:

```
while month < 13:
    print "Month: " + str(month)
    print "Minimum monthly payment: " + str(round(minimum_monthly_payment, 2))
    print "Remaining balance: " + str(round(balance, 2))
    balance = (balance - (balance*monthlyPaymentRate))*(1+(annualInterestRate/12))
    month += 1
```

Also, to make your code much easier to read (and much more Pythonic), you can use Python's built-in list structures, rather than using your own while loop:

```
for month in range(1, 13):
    print "Month: %d" % month
    print "Minimum monthly payment: %d" % round(minimum_monthly_payment, 2)
    print "Remaining balance: %d" % round(balance, 2)
    balance = (balance - (balance * monthlyPaymentRate)) * (1 + (annualInterestRate / 12)
```